# Couchdb database too large to compact?

Tags: couchdb

I'm running couchdb v1.0.1 on an ubuntu linux server. The issue is that the compaction process is failing because I've got a ~1 TB drive with ~TB of a single database. How can I compact the DB or add more space without losing any DB data?

Answer (score 2):

If you can have temporary access to another server with enough free space, you can replicate your database to that new server, redirect all requests to that server, remove the original database, and finally replicate the temporary database back to the original server.

Or you might want to simply replicate the database to a new server with a larger driver and shut the old server down.

Comment: Is there no way to compact on the same server? Replication would take fairly long time and we don't happen to have another server with the requisite space. Downtime isn't an issue, btw, we're not live yet, but the data is still important.

Comment: Well, that's just the problem: CouchDB won't delete the old file until the new file is live, so you need enough space on your server to store both. You could try using a cloud server for a few hours, shouldn't cost more than a few dollars.